# Input Space After Specific Word and Make Capital First Letter

Tags: php, laravel

I have add edit and del in line like this adduser,edituser,deluser & I want to make space in between them & first latter make capital like this output I want

Add User
Edit User
Del User

How can I do that? I have try `preg_replace` with regex but no luck. Does Laravel have any function to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$add = array_map("strrev", array_reverse(str_split(strrev('adduser'), 4)));
$edit = array_map("strrev", array_reverse(str_split(strrev('edituser'), 4)));
$del = array_map("strrev", array_reverse(str_split(strrev('deluser'), 4)));

echo ucwords(implode(' ', $add));
echo ucwords(implode(' ', $edit));
echo ucwords(implode(' ', $del));
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay sir, but I have add,edit,del text in array & many adduser its just an example because I want to a space after this 3 text like there is adduser & addmobile or addpeople so I want to put space after add, hope I clear my question.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution I am using this code

```
$page_list = ['add,edit,del'];

{{ ucwords(trans(preg_replace('/(add|edit|del)/', '$1' . " ", $page_list))) }}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).